# Python. Почему мне нужно обойти список дважды, чтобы удалить все пустые элементы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте. Я хочу избавиться от пустых слов в списке.

```
file_obj = open('D:\sentences.txt.txt', 'r')

lower_text = ''
text = file_obj.readlines()
for line in text:
    lower_text += line.lower()

words = re.split('[^a-z]', lower_text)

a = 0
for word in words:
    for word in words:
        if word == '':
            words.remove('')
            a += 1
print(a)   
print(words)
```

- Я открываю файл с текстом. Сохраняю его в переменную.
- Считываю файл по строкам. Сохраняю в строку. Привожу их к нижнему регистру.
- Разбиваю строку по словам в список.
- Тут я хочу убрать "пустые слова" (''). Использую переменную `а`, чтобы показать удаленные пустые элементы списка. НО, если проходить один раз по списку, то не удаляет все пустые элементы. Почему?

**Screenshots**:

1. Скрин текстового файла. Не нашел как прикрепить С: 
   [image: Скрин текстового файла. Не нашел как прикрепить С:]
2. Я обхожу список один раз и удаляется только 91/129 пустых
   элементов.
   [image: На втором я обхожу список один раз и удаляется только 91/129 пустых элементов.]
3. Если обойти два раза все пустые элементы удаляются.
   [image: На первом скриншоте все пустые элементы удалились.]

Comment: Нельзя удалять элементы из списка, который в данный момент используется в цикле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете с успехом удалять элементы из списка `words`, потому что вы его используете *одновременно для итераций* (в цикле `for`). Примените цикл `for` для его копии:

```
for word in words[:]:
    if word == '':
        words.remove('')
        a += 1
```

(`words[:]` обыкновенная практика как из списка сделать его копию.)

Answer (score 0):

Весь этот цикл:

```
for word in words:
    for word in words:
        if word == '':
            words.remove('')
            a += 1
```

Можно заменить на простое:

```
words = list(filter(lambda word: word != '', words))
```

[Здесь](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) можно почитать о функции `filter`

Comment: Да. действительно все работает. Спасибо) А не могли бы почему мой код работает не так?

Comment: Честно, не знаю. Возможно что-то происходит не так во время "сплита". Попробуйте делать так как посоветовал @AlexanderZonov. И чаще старайтесь использовать встроенные функции Python.

Comment: @hnf  и проголосуйте за ответ если он Вам помог

Comment: С радостью, но не хватает репутации(

Comment: @hnf стрелочка наверх слева от ответа и кнопка "принять ответ", вы их не видите?

Comment: можно заменить на
`words = list(filter(None, words))`

Answer (score 0):

1. Используйте метод [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), чтобы загрузить сразу весь файл в переменную.
2. Используйте регулярное выражение `[^a-z]+` вместо `[^a-z]` в с функцией `split`.

Comment: Окей. спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('D:\sentences.txt.txt') as f:
    words = list(filter(bool, map(str.lower, re.split('[^a-z]', f.read()))))
```